# Permit array in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "pizza",
    "ingredients": [
        {"name": "tomato", "amount": 3, "unit": "un"},
        {"name": "chesse", "amount": 100, "unit": "gr"}
    ]
}
```

And I pass this JSON using POST to my controller, then I need to trust this paramters but I'm not be able to permit the array of hash `ingredients`.

How to permit it?
I tried `params.permit(:ingredients).permit(:name, :amount, :unit).to_h`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`params.permit(:name, :ingredients => [:name, :amount,:unit])` should do the trick.

Read [Nested Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters).