# Permit multidimensional params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive this params:

```
<ActionController::Parameters 
  {"page_hierarchy"=>
      [<ActionController::Parameters 
          {"id"=>"6", "children"=>[
                         {"id"=>"1", "children"=>[{"id"=>"2"}, 
                         {"id"=>"5"}, 
                         {"id"=>"3"}, 
                         {"id"=>"18"}, 
                         {"id"=>"4"}]}]} permitted: false>]} permitted: false>
```

The page `"page_hierarchy"` is an array consisting of several `"{id: , children: }"` elements.
A `children` as well is an array consisting of several `"{id: , children: }"` elements.

**How can I permit params in this format?**

Solutions like this one, did not work for me, because the array is multidimensional [Permit array in params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208549/permit-array-in-params)

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do this by permitting a hash instead of an array, like so:

```
params.permit(page_hierarchy: {})
```

[Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) explains in further detail:

> Sometimes it is not possible or convenient to declare the valid keys
>   of a hash parameter or its internal structure. Just map to an empty
>   hash:
>
> params.permit(preferences: {}) but be careful because this opens the
>   door to arbitrary input. In this case, permit ensures values in the
>   returned structure are permitted scalars and filters out anything
>   else.

Since your params are deeply nested you may have to whitelist the entire hash, which you can do with `permit!`, but be aware that this may have introduce security issues:

```
params.permit!(:page_hierarchy)
```

Again, taken from [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters):

> To whitelist an entire hash of parameters, the permit! method can be
>   used:
>
> params.require(:log_entry).permit! This marks the :log_entry
>   parameters hash and any sub-hash of it as permitted and does not check
>   for permitted scalars, anything is accepted. Extreme care should be
>   taken when using permit!, as it will allow all current and future
>   model attributes to be mass-assigned.